# How can i access AD Server through ldap_functions using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dns, active-directory

i want to connect Ad using ldap_functions.

i only know the username,password and domain name.

using these values i can init,connect,bind with AD.

But ldap_search function will failed.

here my code

```
errorCode = ldap_search_s(
                    pLdapConnection,    // Session handle
                    pMyDN,              // DN to start search
                    LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, // Scope  LDAP_SCOPE_BASE LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
                    pMyFilter,          // Filter
                    NULL,               // Retrieve list of attributes
                    0,                  // Get both attributes and values
                    &pSearchResult);
```

in pMyDN value i specified "DC=SANJU,DC=CO,DC=IN".

the return code gives 10.the error is LDAP_REFERRAL.

But i put pMyDN value into "OU=Marketing,DC=SANJU,DC=CO,DC=IN"

now  its succeed.

But the problem is "i dont know other users OU,then how can i get OU for the user?

or how can achieve this without OU?

note:i have only username,password,domain name only.

Comment: You should post some code on how you search and detail how it failed.

Comment: @ J.N @ patriiice : See my updated question

Comment: server that you are connected to with ldap_open API, is it domain controller for sanju.co.in ? Or it is controller for another domain and there is trust between them ? Also DC (domain controler) should be global catalog server